# Repetitive text fragments extraction algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nlp, text-extraction

I wonder if there is an effective algorithm for extracting most frequent repetitive phrases, words and word fragments in a certain language corpus, and encoding it to shortened unique keys like "oh my god > omg" for effective manual typing.

Keys must be unique to get expanded on the fly, like in Mac Os text expansion feature.

Is there an academic term for such a thing?

Comment: ZIP compressor works using that mechanism, i.e. it generates a DICTIONARY of repetitive strings and then deploys the relevant Dictionary entry key instead of the actual string. You may try looking that its algorithm.